# How does twitter open edge's share functionality on clicking "Share post via.."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, share, navigator

[image: Share post via]

Navigator.share in my code doesn't open this frame, but sometimes just fails, and sometimes opens MAC's own share menu

```js
 if (navigator.share) {
      navigator
        .share({
          title: event?.contract_name,
          text: "Challenge",
          url: contract?.contract_link,
          files: filesArray,
        })
        .then(() => console.log("Successful share"))
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error sharing", error));
    }
```

Comment: Are you triggering this code with a user action?

Comment: Yes, if it were a callback, it wouldn't even be opening MAC's share menu.